# How to remove classpath in Windows7 enviroment

Tags: java, windows-7, classpath

I am trying to configure JBOSS 5.1.0 GA. While configuring, I by mistake added a wrong class path by using this command

```
Set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;some/wrong/path;/again/some/wrong/path/;Opps/Wrong/Path/Again;
```

So I need to remove these wrong class path; when I tried to add a correct class path in this variable like this

```
Set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;correct/path/this/time;
```

I got this output on echo command

```
echo "%CLASSPATH%
```

output: -

```
 %CLASSPATH%;some/wrong/path;/again/some/wrong/path/;Opps/Wrong/Path/Again;correct/path/this/time;
```

I thought setting a classpath again will overwrite the previous path I have added [Wrong once], but instead it added the correct classpath along with wrong class path's.

So, can someone provide me some example or command how to remove or overwrite Classpath.

I am using Window 7 Enterprise addition and I have done this using command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Set blank classpath, and press Enter

use this command :
"set CLASSPATH= "

and press Enter.

And try echo %CLASSPATH% to verify

Setting blank value, automatically removes previously stored value.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
Set CLASSPATH=correct/path/this/time;
```

Comment: What about previous class path, I have no idea what previous class paths are which are included in %CLASSPATH% ;

Comment: Echo it first and then you can copy all the required paths and set it directly as mentioned above

Comment: I tried echo, but It always returns %CLASSPATH%;SOME/WRONG/CLASS/PATH ...
So, I am not able to get the values in %CLASSPATH% ..

Comment: it tells that earlier the classpath was not set to any value.

Answer (score 0):

If set through the command prompt CLASSPATH and %CLASSPATH% are instance only temporary variables. Just close the prompt and open a new window.

If they are set in the Environment Variables under the System settings they should be easily edited there in most Windows operating systems.